# How to add an html document to a container within another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on an application similar to http://www.stumbleupon.com. In which I have a php request to get the whole html of a page, and I store it in a javascript variable.

Like so:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'http://localhost/newsPage/index.php', type: "POST", dataType:'html', data: "url="+ url,

success: function(msg){
    msg.append()
    var opened = window.open("news");
    opened.document.write(msg);
}
```

Where "msg" contains the whole html of an external page, say http://www.nytimes.com

The issue is that I do not want to open an exact replica of the external page as I am doing now, but I want to embed that content to another file that has additional functionality.

I would love if I could put all the content within that msg variable within a div. To achieve a similar effect as stumbleupon's navigation. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> I would love if I could put all the content within that msg variable within a div

Use jQuery [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method.

```
$( "#mydiv" ).load( "http://localhost/newsPage/index.php" ); // where mydiv is the id of target div
```

The method will send a GET POST ajax request by default, if you pass an object as data (*optional*) it'll send POST instead.

Otherwise you can just do

```
$("#mydiv").append(msg); // where mydiv is the id of target div
```

Inside your ajax request, assuming msg is a valid HTML string (*not an entire document, just the content you wish to populate inside the div*)